# Redirecionamento em javascript não funciona com script externo

Tags: javascript

Redirecionamento em javascript não funciona com script externo.

Tenho uma página com o seguinte código:

```
<input type="text" name="login" id="login">
<input type="password" name="senha" id="senha">
<button type="button" id="btnEntrar">Entrar</button>
<script src="js/functions-index.js"></script>
```

Na minha página `functions-index.js:`

```
        var btnEntrar = document.getElementById('btnEntrar');
        var login = document.getElementById('login');
        var senha = document.getElementById('senha');


        btnEntrar.addEventListener('click', function(){

          if(login.value ==''){
            alert("Preencha o campo email");
          }
          else if(login.senha == ''){
            alert("Preencha o campo senha");
          }
          else if(login.senha === '123'){
                console.log(login.value);
                location.href = "pag2.html";


          }


 });
```

Porém, o redirecionamento não funciona.Nem mesmo com `href`, `location`, `replace` e etc
Nenhum erro é retornado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="login" id="login">
<input type="password" name="senha" id="senha">
<button type="button" id="btnEntrar">Entrar</button>
<script src="js/functions-index.js"></script>
```

**JavasScript**

Falta fechar o script com `});`

Altere  `login.senha`  por  `senha.value`

```
    var btnEntrar = document.getElementById('btnEntrar');
    var login = document.getElementById('login');
    var senha = document.getElementById('senha');


   btnEntrar.addEventListener('click', function(){

      if(login.value ==''){
        alert("Preencha o campo email");
      }
      else if(senha.value == ''){
        alert("Preencha o campo senha");
      }
      else if(senha.value === '123'){
            //console.log(login.value);
            alert(login.value);
            location.href = "pag2.html";


      }
  });
```